# Spark program structure: broadcast variables vs final static vs external static attributes in classes

Tags: java, apache-spark, architecture, spark-streaming

I have an application which should read from a file some lines and make of them a final variable which will be used as reference.
As of now, before the beginning of the spark context, I launch a static method in a class (called People) class which

```
reads the file;
fill a final static HashTable;
static{ hashTable.put(eachline);}
```

In the transformation code I have, for example:

```
JavaRDD<String> filteredRDD = anotherRDD.filter( new Function<String,Boolean>(){
    public Boolean call(String s){
        People.hashTable.containsKey(s);
    }
});
```

Doubts:

1. Should I use a Broadcast Variable initialized immediately after the `SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaKafkaStream").setMaster("local[2]");` declaration?
2. Why should I choose a Broadcast Variable above a final one? As far as I can see, finals are passed smoothly inside the transformation flow.
3. Is it the correct/elegant procedure to load somewhere the file content before the beginning of a SparkStreaming computation?
4. If I had external classes which took care of some of the computation (for readability, mostly), would I prefer to access to those methods in a static way or instantiate the classe in a `rdd.foreachPartition(....` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### 1) Should we use a broadcast variable?

YES

### 2) Broadcast variable vs static initialized variable

**Do not use static variables for passing serialized data.**

In general, a static variable with data **will not work with Spark** when we scale up the the job to more than 1 machine in a cluster (It looks like it works not, b/c Spark is running in `local(2)` mode.

Static fields are part of the object initialization and are not part of the serialized form, as they can/should be reconstructed at the receiving side in a remoting operation. Note that it *could* work, if the object is smart enough to rebuild its contents on deserialization.

Instead, we could use a normal instance, which can be serialized. (like `mydata = new HashMap<>(); mydata.put(...)`

### 2.1) Instance variable vs a broadcast variable

Let's say we have a large dataset, with 420 partitions and a cluster of 8 executor nodes. In an operation like:

```
val referenceData = Map(...)
val filtered = rdd.filter(elem => referenceData.get(elem) > 10)
```

The `referenceData` object will be serialized 420 times, or as many tasks as are required to execute the transformation.

Instead, a broadcast variable:

```
val referenceDataBC = sparkContext.broadcast(Map(...))
val filtered = rdd.filter(elem => referenceDataBC.value.get(elem) > 10)
```

will be sent once to each executor, or 8 times total. Hence, saving a lot of network and CPU by reducing the serialization overhead.

### 3) Is it the correct/elegant procedure to load somewhere the file content before the beginning of a SparkStreaming computation?

We will need to load external data before the streaming process is started. What other choices do we have?

### 4) Use functions in a static way or instantiate the class in a rdd.foreachPartition(....)

Depends if the function requires context provided by the class or not. 
e.g. needs context:

```
rdd.foreachPartition{ iter =>
    val jsonParser = new JsonParser(validation)
    val parsed = iter.map(jsonParser.parse)
    ...
}
```

e.g. doesn't need context

```
vectors.foreachPartition{ iter =>
    val magnitudes = iter.map(elem => MyVectorMath.modulus(elem))
}
```

Comment: Thank you. About the static initialized variables: I am using some static finals as constant (separator for split operations, paths) which I guess I'm good with, but other static final maps, like you mentioned, for reference data.  
If I understood correctly: when I do a put operations in those, even if they are in serializable classes, I may have inconsistencies among the JVMs in the cluster. Correct?

Comment: Another question, which I was a little embarassed to put with the others:  
If I wanted to avoid having a giant main class and having some of the computation in other classes, should I broadcast them? Or is it actually normal to have a big main method?

Comment: @vale constants are fine, and actually a lot better than closing over local variables. (b/c sometimes the pull other elements into the closure, leading to serialization issues). Static mutable variables will be uninitialized in the executors of the cluster. This typically results in null pointer exceptions. There's a use for that, when managing local resources (like thread pools, db connections, ...)

Comment: I don't really understand the last comment. You can modularize your spark program as you would with any other stack. (btw, I'd recommend using Scala instead of Java - much better/concise syntax and uniformity of the api between local (scala) and distributed (spark)  operations.  )

Comment: I have 10 days for this project PoC and cannot study Scala right now, but it's on my list for this summer.
The other question: the classes used to modularize contain data that would normally (locally) be static. I'm guessing here lies again a problemBut for a variable substitution, an Accumulator wouldn't be sufficient: should I create a new broadcast it everytime it changes?
I must admit I have other questions which are not answered by the Spark Documentation (as far as I can see): where did you find these kind of answers (program structure)? Could I ask again for your help?

Comment: @Vale you can always ask questions here on SO. Try to focus on one at the time (not 4 like here :-) ). There're plenty of brilliant people that are willing to help and the responses will help future visitors as well.

Comment: @vale PS: why use static fields to keep data? unless it's a global, immutable dictionary (or alike), use instances.

Comment: PS-> The data I receive is quite fast, but always for a bunch of indentifiable IDs : I have built a Map<String,String> associating the ID to the "last useful" string of data. The case checks a timestamp and a couple of values against what I stored in the Map and substitute the value if the conditions give a true. This is done in a class where there is no Spark code, which then takes action (saving the file, sending a mail, doing a HTTP request). Static because it must be equal for the class instances. Let me guess, though, I should change the Map to an RDD storing those informations...

Comment: @Vale sounds like there could be other (scalable) ways to approach that problem. check out `mapWithState` in sparkStreaming.